# How block all theme css for custom widget in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I'm creating a custom Wordpress widget. I want this widget to look the same in all themes. I've identified the widget's appearance properties with the custom CSS file. However, since each theme has different styling properties for the widgets, the widget looks different on different themes. Is there a way to disable the style properties of the themes used for the widgets?

Comment: I think the only way to disable all page's CSS for your widget is to display it in an iFrame. Otherwise you can't guarantee a css rule could modify its appearance.

Comment: It's not a good idea, it's got to be a right way. @gael

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain well, I was thinking about services such as Facebook, Google map or YouTube which deliver their 'widgets' from external services in iFrames. So if you embed a map for example it will create an iFrame on your page that will serve its own html, css... where page's CSS aren't effective. In Wordpress, widgets are displayed in the DOM of the page and as far as I know they can't be disconnected of its CSS styles.